# Cartesian Coordinate Trigonometric Problem

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

I need help with solving this problem.

Find the value of $\sin2x$, if $\cot x = -\frac{7}{24}$, and $x$ is obtuse.

My attempt to this problem,  was as follows :

First I knew that $\cot x$ equals a negative value,  so the terminal arm must lie in the $2$-nd or $4$-th quadrant.  I made the terminal arm be in the second quadrant,  which will make $x$ be an obtuse angle.  Then I found my hypotenuse,  which is $25$, then I wrote the trigonometric ratios for cosine and sine.  Which were : $\cos x  = -\frac{7}{25}$ , $\sin x = \frac{24}{25}$. I then used the double angle formula for sine, to substitute my ratios in it, and solve.   $$\sin 2x = 2\sin x \cos x$$, and I got $$\sin 2x = -2 \cdot \frac{24}{25} \cdot \frac{7}{25} = -\frac{366}{625}$$

Did I solve this problem correctly ?

Comment: As $$\sin2x=\cdots=\dfrac{2\cot x}{1+\cot^2x}$$  What is the use of "obtuse"?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee This is what it said in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct. It's nice that the problem made use of the $7, 24, 25$ Pythagorean triple.